# Do I need to call close connection?

Tags: symfony1, doctrine, symfony-1.4, doctrine-1.2

In the application I use `Doctrine_Query::create()` many times.

Do I need to call close connection each time I use it? Or will doctrine do it for me ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creating a query does not make a new connection, so you don't need to worry at all. There is a single connection established each request by the Doctrine connection manager, and all your queries will go over that connection.

Answer (score 3):

Each query is sharing the same connection. There is no need to close it.

You can examine `Doctrine_Manager` to see how this is done.